# tint2: Fontconfig error

Tags: 12.04, fonts, tint2

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am attempting to configure tint2, I got it installed and ready to go, but when I go to the terminal and start it up by typing tint2 I get this:

```
    real transparency on... depth: 32
    xRandr: Found crtc's: 6
    xRandr: Linking output LVDS with crtc 0
    tint2 : another systray is running pid=6801
    tint2 : nb monitor 1, nb monitor used 1, nb desktop 1
    Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

I'm guessing the problem lies in the fontconfig error, I tried downloading a fonts.conf from http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/fontconfig-error/ and putting it into /usr/share/fonts but it didn't work either. Does anyone know how to fix this? I also tried putting it into my home directory with the same results

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018056/font-config-error-launching-google-chrome-stable-from-the-command-line-on-14-04

Comment: The content of your font config file would be helpful in answering this question.