# Fontconfig error: cannot load default config file

Tags: 14.04, fonts

Having issues when I start most graphical programs. Simply just says

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

I can confirm that `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` exists and has the correct permissions.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5497 Jan 16 09:55 fonts.conf
```

I'm not getting any other information associated with this error, and searching hasn't provided any helpful information either.

What can I do to fix this?

running gedit, geany, chromium-browser, firefox, libreoffice...
Basically any graphical program that uses fonts

**EDIT**
using `strace` i've found the problem stems from here:

```
access("/data/jenkins/pms-deps-universal/BUILD_TAG/linux-ubuntu-i686/output/pms-depends-linux-ubuntu-i686-release-8400c3b/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Fontconfig error: ", 18Fontconfig error: )      = 18
write(2, "Cannot load default config file", 31Cannot load default config file) = 31
```

I've never used Jenkins before, I'll try removing it and see what happens

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

This returns that jenkins is not installed...

I don't even have a `/data/` partition.

How can I change the path for Fontconfig?

Comment: Could you provide an example of which programs and/or commands that return this error.

Comment: edited. no special commands

Comment: I meant if you could give at least *one* example of something so one could recreate the error.

Comment: I did! simply open a terminal and type gedit. that's exactly what I'm doing. Everything still works fine, I just get that annoying error.

Comment: Why would Fontconfig be looking for conf files under Jenkins?

Comment: I've just now noticed that if I use `sudo` to open any program I no longer have fontconfig errors. What could be going on with this?

Comment: what are the  permissions for /etc/fonts directory?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018056/font-config-error-launching-google-chrome-stable-from-the-command-line-on-14-04

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the `$FONTCONFIG_PATH` properly. Usually it is set in `/etc/profile` but, if you are executing the command from a non login shell (e.g., through cron), then you need to set it explicitly by doing the following:

```
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts
```

Comment: This is an actual answer to the question I actually asked! Too bad I can't test and see if it helps as it's been over a year since I asked the question, I've since updated, upgraded, and moved on from this issue.  Thank you though, for actually answering the actual question.

Answer (score 8):

Just before fontconfig is built, it is configured.  This hard codes the paths where it looks for various files.  The fontconfig your program is linked to is not configured correctly.  Fontconfig should be configured like this:

```
./configure --enable-static --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var
```

This will make fontconfig look for `fonts.conf` in `/etc/fonts` instead of `/data/jenkins/pms-deps-universal/BUILD_TAG/linux-ubuntu-i686/output/pms-depends-linux-ubuntu-i686-release-8400c3b/etc/fonts`.

Comment: To those who want to delete this answer.  What's wrong with it?  This is the correct answer to why fontconfig displays the referenced error message.  Just because you don't like the idea of rebuilding fontconfig from source does not make it an invalid answer.

Comment: It doesn't work with me that command ! please help me