# Python plots won't display: "Font config error"

Tags: 14.04, python, fonts, pycharm

I am trying to plot some histograms with `matplotlib.pyplot` through the PyCharm IDE. Whenever I run my project, I get the same thing:

> Font config error: cannot load default config file

and no plots ever appear. My fonts'conf file is where it should be, has the proper permissions, and I've never modified it, so I don't know what's wrong. What should I try?

edit: If I try to plot something through a python console within PyCharm, it works fine, it just won't work within a python module that I am trying to run through pycharm.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file) help?

Comment: @edwinksl No, I've already looked at that. I think it is important that my issue is in the context of PyCharm. Doing the suggested solution on that post changed nothing.

Comment: Ah I see. It is good practice to say what you have tried in your question so that we don't waste time on things you already tried.