# Dell Edge Gateway 5100 - Ubuntu Core 16.04 - Fontconfig error

Tags: dell, fonts, gateway

I have been developing a Snappy application on the Dell Gateway for the last year.  I am nearing the end of development and I am experience a fault that I need some help with.  If needed, can this be forwarded to the technical support appropriate for the issue.

The application is a Java application and includes the necessary JRE environment with the snap app.

I am getting the following system level error messages:

```
      Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
      Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

I do not think the Fontconfig is an available application in the OS environment.  I was instructed by another vendor it appears the underlying OS may not be properly initializing the AWT environment.

Does this make sense?  Has this been encountered and resolved on the Dell GW Ubuntu environment?

Below are some online threads of similar issues.

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/fontconfig-error/
[Fontconfig error: cannot load default config file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790659/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file-on-ubuntu-16-04

Regards,

Jerry Marti

Comment: Resolved. Added a fonts folder inside my snap app writable space and within added default fonts.conf file.  In the yaml file I added  FONTCONFIG_FILE and FONTCONFIG_PATH environment variables pointing to my local fonts.conf file.