# Cannot load config file from /etc/fonts/fonts.conf

Tags: fonts, 18.10

Upon invoking emacs, it report errrors:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file from /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

Consult with the answer at [Fontconfig error: cannot load default config file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file).

```
me@alpha:~:
$ echo $FONTCONFIG_PATH
/etc/fonts
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work.

How could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command

```
dpkg -l | grep fontconfig
```

I suspect that you find that the listed packages are not of the same version, which they should be. In that case the obvious solution is to update your system to the most recent packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I suppose you are on 18.10, btw. This problem shouldn't show up on 19.04; see this bug report:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896684

Comment: Doesn't work for me:

$ dpkg -l | grep fontconfig ii fontconfig 2.13.1-2ubuntu2 amd64 generic font configuration library - support binaries ii fontconfig-config 2.13.1-2ubuntu2 all generic font configuration library - configuration ii libfontconfig1:amd64 2.13.1-2ubuntu2 amd64 generic font configuration library - runtime ii libfontconfig1:i386 2.13.1-2ubuntu2 i386 generic font configuration library - runtime

Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file from /etc/fonts/fonts.conf Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault

Comment: @Peter: You'd better ask an own question, and provide some details on what steps resulted in that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was able to solve it by deleting (moving for safety) the `/etc/fonts` folder and reinstalling `fontconfig`

```
mv /etc/fonts /etc/fonts.bak
sudo apt install fontconfig --reinstall
```