# font config error launching google-chrome-stable from the command line on 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, fonts

I ended up here with a very similar error to [Fontconfig error: cannot load default config file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-filewhen) launching the latest google-chrome-stable (Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)) from the command line with the intent of locking it to the launch bar. The aforementioned which I received when updating today.

The exact output received is as follows:

`$ google-chrome-stable`

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[4946:4946:0321/143522.945617:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1019)] Lost UI shared context.
[1:10:0321/143522.993869:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(114)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Shared memory handle is not valid
[4946:4985:0321/143528.000996:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[4946:4985:0321/143528.189366:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[4946:4985:0321/143528.302925:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[4946:4985:0321/143528.761029:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
Fontconfig error: line 152: mismatched tag
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[4946:4985:0321/143809.554796:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I noticed was the warning regarding line 146 in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` which only had the `</blank>` tag on the line line so I removed it. Then I noticed the error on line 152. I attempted the accepted answer to the question linked in the question above to no positive affect so I assumed that line 152 was the problem. Upon further review of the file I noticed that line 152 only contains a `</config>` tag and found a corresponding `<config>` tag on line 80 so I decided that can't be it as everything between `<config>` and `</config>` looks pretty important. Then I noticed the `<blank>` tag  on line 86 and decided  that I had inadvertently broken the file by removing the ending tag with out the beginning tag. So I removed line 86 as well and saved the file.

This approach resolved the problem immediately.

Comment: Do you still get this though? `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file`   I see it in a couple of issues, ie. [here's one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1003690#c8)

Comment: `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` I made an issue about it, because it's due to sandboxing: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1010388

Comment: @howaboutsynergy I had this issue on bare metal with the versions mentioned. My answer reflects that reality. I have not had that issue since. Chromium isn't Chrome.